# Features from personalized Google Maps map not visible on Android device

Tags: google-maps, android

I have developed a personalized Google map and shared it with fellow colleagues within our organization. However, when attempting to access the map through Android devices, we encounter issues where certain features from certain layers are not visible, and others are only partially visible. I attempted to reimport the KML file with geometries and even created a new map, but unfortunately, that did not resolve the issue.

Does anyone have an idea what could be a problem? Is it possible that Google is billing this service according to the number of views, and that I might have some form of restricted access?

Comment: Can you share the KML and the link to the map?  Also, if you suspect that it is the number if hits to the map then have a coworker make that map through their Google account and see if the issue persists.